# Django-reviews: cannot set content-type

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using django-reviews (http://code.google.com/p/django-reviews/) and having trouble setting the content-type for a review. Simple example:

```
def check_review(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        reviewed_item = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=request.POST['object_pk']) 
        review_form = ReviewForm(target_object=reviewed_item, data=request.POST) 
        review_form.content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(MyModel)
```

However the form's 'content_type' field has no value and the form has 
the error "(Hidden field content_type) This field is required." I've 
tried to set the content_type multiple ways with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you can set form values with

```
review_form.base_fields["content_type"] = ...
```

though this still didn't seem to work for content_type. This was actually a mistake on my part. I meant to instantiate a Review object after the form was validated and set the content_type on that object. Much easier.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, I'm going with the assumption you see the form displayed, you fill it in the values and try to submit. At this point, you see form validation error indicating you need the hidden field filled in. Is that correct?

If so, you need to set the content_type on the form before submitting. Normally I do something like this:

```
def check_review(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        reviewed_item = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=request.POST['object_pk'])
        review_form = ReviewForm(target_object=reviewed_item, data=request.POST)
        if review_form.is_valid():
            # do some processing here
    else:
        # We're just getting an unbound form
        reviewed_item = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=request.POST['object_pk'])
        review_form = ReviewForm(target_object=reviewed_item, data=request.POST)
        review_form.content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(MyModel)
    # return with review_form in the template's context or what have you
```

Comment: I'm actually using this to record star ratings from users. The star rating and user get posted, and then I want to fill in the rest of the data (content_type, etc) in the check_review function. I assigned the content_type like this with django's comments but it doesn't seem to be working with django-reviews.